# Free or open-source PDF editing software for Windows

Tags: windows, pdf, pdf-editor

I'm seeking for open-source software that allows you to edit PDF files with a range of options similar to Adobe Acrobat's one.

I found Sejda a good online tool for this purpose since it includes a lot of options (its cropping option is remarkable: it overlaps all the pages of the document to show you how far you can reduce margins without eliminating words or content). However, it is not free and it allows you for a maximum of editions per day, and his editor has lacks (it does not allow you to remove figures, edit text easily, etc.).

Is there any free or open-source software that includes a range of options similar to Adobe Acrobat's or Sejda's ones? And which is available on Windows 10?

Comment: [Free PDF editor for Windows](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/19011/3579)

Comment: I use LibreDraw (part of the LibreOffice suite); can't be installed separately, unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

You can try [DeftPDF](https://deftpdf.com). It's a web-based PDF editor and converter online and has functions similar to the site you mentioned. It's free on most tools that involve editing and converting. So far, the only tool that has a fee is the PDF translator, which only asks for a fee when you upload something lengthy but the rest is all free.